# UIView in UIScrollView does not adjust width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios8, uiscrollview

I have been searching through stackOverflow and whatever google proposes but I wasn't able to get it to work. I am intending to draw a simple 2D Graph in a scrollview, the distance between my datapoints is `kStepX` and I want the scrollview to be at least the width of the screen, if I have more datapoints it should scroll but no more than 100 points.

I think I have a problem with my Autolayout and sizing the contentWidth, so here is what I have done so far:

1. I added a UIScrollView with the following constraints:

   - Leading Space to Superview =0
   - Top space to superview =0
   - Height = width of superview
   - Width = width of superview
2. I then added a UIView (called GraphView) as a Child with the following constraints:

   - zero space to all 4 bounds of scrollview
   - center X and center Y to scrollview

in my GraphViewController I set the contenSize as:

```
historyScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH,sizeof(data)*kStepX), kGraphHeight);
```

but it does not scroll!
if I set a fix width in the storyboard the scrollview scrolls further than I have data..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be setting the `contentSize` of the `scrollView` when using auto layout. That should be calculated from your constraints if they are setup correctly.

What you are missing is to set a width and height constraints on the view inside the scrollView. A `scrollView` determines it's `contentSize` based on the size the subviews have. Since an `UIView` does not have an intrinsic size, you will need to add `width` and `height` constraints to it, then update it when you need it with the right value

Something like this should work:

```
innerViewWidthConstraint.constant = MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH,sizeof(data)*kStepX) 
innerViewHeightConstraint.constant = kGraphHeight

// You might need to layout the views too
[historyScrollView layoutIfNeeded]
```

Hope this helps! Good luck :)

Comment: thank you Catalina, I added the Constraint via code and placed a placeholder-width-Constraint in the Autolayout, it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take ScrollView in side in your Main View and give `Top`,`Bottom`,`Leading`,`Trailing`,`Center X` and `Center Y`.

after take `GraphView` inside you `scrollview` and also set constrain of `GraphView`.

set height of `GraphView`

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *HeightGraphView;
```

whenEver you set your  `HeightGraphView` then automatically set ScrollView contentSize.

see my demo its working for Vertically scrolling, apply same for Horizontal scrolling.

[Demo Vertical Scrolling](http://ge.tt/5r5b1mC2/v/0)